# Actualizar un JTable dentro de un ciclo For

Tags: java, java-swing, jtable

Tengo un problema a la hora de ejecutar un programa. Estoy simulando un Procesador con java y estoy guardando las variables en una lista y mostrandolas en un JTable, en este programa tengo una variable que es la de ciclos que debe ir en decremento cada que llamo a un Threar.sleep(). Todo eso si lo hace mi programa el problema que tengo es a la hora de mostrar mis datos.

la parte que hace la resta de los ciclos esta dentro de un Do while y un ciclo For
por lo que entiendo el For es el que no me deja Actualizar mi JTable me interesa que se vea como se va restando los ciclos y los estados en la tabla. la única manera en la que he podido hacer que se muestren los cambios en mi JTable es poniendo un JOptionPane.ShowMessage no sé si exista una forma de actualizar mi jtable o si tienen alguna propuesta para poder actualizar mi JTable

este es el código que utilizo:

```
        if(e.getSource()==frmControl.btnEjecutar){
        IProcesoDao dao = new ProcesoDaoImpl();
        List<mdlProceso> Proceso = new ArrayList<>();
        do{
            int ciclos;
            Proceso=dao.Obtener();
            frmControl.gridMostrarProceso(Proceso);
           for(int i =0; i<Proceso.size();i++){
            ciclos = Integer.parseInt(Proceso.get(i).getCiclos());
            if(Nuevo(Proceso.get(i).getStatus())||
                    Procesando(Proceso.get(i).getStatus())){
                if( ciclos>0){
                   dao.ciclosAct(modProceso,String.valueOf(Proceso.get(i).getPid()));
                   dao.actualizar(modProceso,String.valueOf(Proceso.get(i).getPid()));
                   estableceTimer();


                }else{
                    dao.finalizar(modProceso,String.valueOf(Proceso.get(i).getPid()));
                    Proceso=dao.Obtener();
                    frmControl.gridMostrarProceso(Proceso);

                }    
            }

           } 
        }while(recorrerTabla()==true);
    }
```

Comment: No es clara la pregunta, pon el JTable, y comenta tú código en la pregunta....

Comment: La mejor forma de realizar esto es haciendo un hilo que con el Thread.sleep() cada cierto tiempo la vaya actualizando.